# Pandoc markdown vertical lines in grid

Tags: text, markdown, pandoc

I use Pandoc (http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) and its Markdown processor. When I convert the grid below to PDF (directly via LaTeX) using Pandoc, there are no vertical lines in PDF. How to obtain them?

```
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Fruit         | Price         | Advantages         |
+===============+===============+====================+
| Bananas       | $1.34         | - built-in wrapper |
|               |               | - bright color     |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Oranges       | $2.10         | - cures scurvy     |
|               |               | - tasty            |
+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I'm sure you could change the LaTeX template Pandoc uses to produce the PDF...

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to add vertical lines, other than postprocessing pandoc's latex output, according to this bug https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/922#issuecomment-38586467

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do this directly. The only solution I know is to use pandoc to convert to LaTeX, then edit the table formatting in LaTeX.